# "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource", When trying to fetch JSON data on React native from Djang rest framework

Tags: json, django, amazon-web-services, react-native

I have some JSON data in a Django app, I deployed the app on AWS, when I try to access it on my browser it works fine, but when I try to fetch on React native, I get: "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource".
That's my code on expo snack:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          'http://53.27.198.111:8000/api/' //that's not my real IP btw
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovies(data.results);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    };
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried django-cors-headers when the Django app was on localhost and it worked fine, but when I deployed it on AWS it's not working anymore.